# How do I create a loop or an array to calculate risk ratios for five different variables?

Tags: r, arrays, loops, tidyverse

I'm calculating risk ratios for several different foods after an outbreak at a picnic (I've made up the data for privacy reasons). The dataset I have is shown below as a tibble:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 7
  patient  sick  apple banana strawberry yogurt sandwich
  <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>   
1 patient1 yes   no    no     yes        no     no      
2 patient2 yes   yes   no     no         yes    no      
3 patient3 no    yes   yes    yes        yes    yes     
4 patient4 yes   no    no     yes        yes    no      
5 patient5 no    no    no     no         yes    no      
6 patient6 no    no    no     no         no     no      
7 patient7 yes   no    no     no         yes    yes
```

There are 7 patients labeled `patient1` through `patient7`. The variable `sick` refers to whether or not the patient got sick after the picnic. Lastly, the columns `apple`, `banana`, `strawberry`, `yogurt`, and `sandwich` are the foods that the patients ate at the picnic. `yes` or `no` refers to whether or not the patient ate the food.

First, I use this code to calculate the number of patients who got sick and who ate each food (in this case an apple):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(epitools)
sick_apple <- picnic %>% 
  group_by(sick, apple) %>% 
  summarise(total=n())
sick_apple
```

The output I get from that code looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   sick [2]
  sick  apple total
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 no    no        2
2 no    yes       1
3 yes   no        3
4 yes   yes       1
```

Next, I use this code to calculate the risk ratios for the apple:

```
apple_table <- matrix(c(2,1,3,1), nrow=2, ncol=2)
apple_table
riskratio.wald(apple_table)
```

Which creates this output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    1    1
> riskratio.wald(apple_table)
$data
          Outcome
Predictor  Disease1 Disease2 Total
  Exposed1        2        3     5
  Exposed2        1        1     2
  Total           3        4     7

$measure
          risk ratio with 95% C.I.
Predictor   estimate     lower    upper
  Exposed1 1.0000000        NA       NA
  Exposed2 0.8333333 0.1751513 3.964825

$p.value
          two-sided
Predictor  midp.exact fisher.exact chi.square
  Exposed1         NA           NA         NA
  Exposed2  0.8571429            1  0.8091498

$correction
[1] FALSE

attr(,"method")
[1] "Unconditional MLE & normal approximation (Wald) CI"
```

In this case the risk ratio for an apple at this picnic is 0.8333333.

This brings me to my question, which is how would I go about creating an array or loop that would continue this process for all other foods (`banana`, `strawberry`, `yogurt`, and `sandwich`). I've never really used arrays or loops in R and have no idea where to start for this. Ideally, it would be nice to get output that nicely and neatly lists the risk ratios for each food all in one place. The reason I'm asking this is because the real dataset I'm working with has about 50 different foods and I'd like to find something quicker than calculating the rate ratio individually for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly this is one way to solve the problem:

0. call the libraries needed (actually dplyr would be enough as I am calling functions from libraries directly but I will list all libraries for you to check if you need to install something)
1. set up dummy data, I am using the data.table packge to read a data.table from text which can be used as a data.frame
2. write the function you want to apply on each data set
3. organise the data in vertical format, split by grouping criteria and apply function on all list items

=> Result will be a named list, where each of the list itens the result set for one food!

I am using mostly `tidyverse` functions as this is what I am most familiar with.

```
library(data.table) # only need this to set up the dummy data below
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidytable)
library(purrr)
library(epitools) # deduced this is the package needed for risk calulatinos


# set up dummy data
mydf <- data.table::fread("patient  sick  apple banana strawberry yogurt sandwich
patient1 yes   no    no     yes        no     no      
patient2 yes   yes   no     no         yes    no      
patient3 no    yes   yes    yes        yes    yes     
patient4 yes   no    no     yes        yes    no      
patient5 no    no    no     no         yes    no      
patient6 no    no    no     no         no     no      
patient7 yes   no    no     no         yes    yes")

# set up funtion to be applied per food 
foo <- function(x){
    # summarize data to vector
    mymat <- dplyr::count(x, sick, value) %>% 
                 # fill possibly missing combinations setting the n variable to 0 for the missing cases
                 tidyr::complete(sick, value, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
                 # guarantee the order 
                 dplyr::arrange(sick, value) %>%
                 # pull out the count variable as a vector
                 dplyr::pull(n) %>%
                 # convert to matrix
                 matrix(nrow=2, ncol=2)
    # perform operation
    ret <- epitools::riskratio.wald(mymat)
    # return value
    return(ret)
}


res <- mydf %>% 
    # make data long
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(patient, sick)) %>%
    # split each group into its own list item
    # tidyr::group_split does almost the same - though it does not name the list automatically which helps later on
    tidytable::group_split.(name, .keep = FALSE, .named = TRUE) %>%
    # apply calculations using the purrr package (pratically it is the equivalent of a loop running over all list items
    purrr::map(~foo(.x))

# since the list is named we can call an item of choice by food name
res[["banana"]]
$data
          Outcome
Predictor  Disease1 Disease2 Total
  Exposed1        2        4     6
  Exposed2        1        0     1
  Total           3        4     7

$measure
      risk ratio with 95% C.I.
Predictor  estimate lower upper
  Exposed1        1    NA    NA
  Exposed2        0     0   NaN

$p.value
          two-sided
Predictor  midp.exact fisher.exact chi.square
  Exposed1         NA           NA         NA
  Exposed2  0.4285714    0.4285714  0.2123172

$correction
[1] FALSE

attr(,"method")
[1] "Unconditional MLE & normal approximation (Wald) CI"
```

Now lets extract only the risk ratios:

```
purrr::map_df(res, ~.x$measure[[2]]) # use `purrr::map()` to get a list instead of a tibble
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  apple banana strawberry yogurt sandwich
  <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1 0.833      0       1.33    1.2    0.833
```

Comment: Thanks so much @DPH. This is very helpful! It will take me some time to sit down and look through the code to understand it but for now this gives me something to work with! Thank you!

Comment: I have another question. Suppose I wanted to have a list of the upper bound or lower bound confidence intervals. How would I extract only the lower bound? (This is located in the $measure section of the output right next to the risk ratio value). I tried using `purrr::map_df(res, ~.x$measure[[3]])` but it just gave me a list of NA values. I put in a 3 instead of a 2 because I figured that was the value that would specify lower bound.

Comment: Never mind @DPH, I think I got it. I was thinking of the numbers in brackets wrong - when I used a `measure[[4]]` I got the lower bound value and when I used `measure[[6]]` I got the upper bound value.